# Angular Material - Getting index of row in data table

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material2

I am using the `MatTable` component from [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) to make a dynamic data table.

I need to get the current position of a row. I can easily get the row on which the user clicked but I am unable to know its current position in the list (which depends on sort/filtering/pagination).

Any idea?

Comment: Do you use `*ngFor` to create rows dynamically?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide No I use mat-rows and mat-cells etc

Answer (score 25, accepted):

in your `mat-cell` you can get index like `*ngFor` as below

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i = index;">
        {{ i }}
</mat-cell>
```

**Update** from Angular 5 use also `index as i`

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="rowIndex">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Index </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;index as i;"> {{ i }} </td>
</ng-container>
```

- `index`: number: The index of the current item in the iterable.
- `first`: boolean: True when the item is the first item in the iterable.
- `last`: boolean: True when the item is the last item in the iterable.
- `even`: boolean: True when the item has an even index in the iterable.
- `odd`: boolean: True when the item has an odd index in the iterable.

Comment: It's not related to row data its just the current row index in the HTML table

Comment: Yes, If you need the index to be related to row data you need to add it to your data, so it will not be changed on sorting or filter

Comment: what do you mean by id of the html row?

Comment: the index of the row will remain even if material angular changes the content ? that is why this angular ngfor work ?

Comment: Yes, its related to loop, not the data

Answer (score 2):

I searched a lot, but for my case "indexOf" scenario doesn't work properly then I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56821027/11257333), and it does exactly what I need.

```
let i = index;
i + (paginator.pageIndex * paginator.pageSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using angularjs or angular2? your title says angularjs but your tags and post say otherwise.

angular2

```
<div *ngFor="item of items; i = index">
  <span click(item, i)>
</div>
```

angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="item of items">
  <span click(item, $index)>
</div>
```

edit: I saw your comments, does this answer help you out? 
[Is there an index property with CDK data table or Material2 data table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45446571/is-there-an-index-property-with-cdk-data-table-or-material2-data-table)

Answer (score 1):

For **Angular 10+**

Try using `index as i`

**Example:**

```
 <ng-container matColumnDef="columnName">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
     </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; index as i">
        <button (click)="selectedItem(i)"> Button </button>
     </td
 </ng-container>
```